# How to connect to my mysql database installed in my host (domain)

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, vb6, mysql-odbc-connector

I want to develop a desktop application (with VB) and connect it to an online database (MySQL), I already had my hosting site and I thought why not create a MySQL database in my domain (which by the way is offered in the pack) and connect my desktop application to this database.
Why an online database? Because I want to develop a mobile application to keep me informed of any changes in my business without moving to my office.

The problem is that my VB6 application cannot connect to my MySQL due to domain restrictions. I wondered how these thousands of apps work with online data? What are their magic solutions? Or did I miss something?

Please any idea? I worked with VB6 and a local database which is no longer productive.

Comment: Sounds to me this is more like a **how to bypass/work around censorship which prevents my app from working properly**.

Comment: @blabla_bingo: Hanlon's Razor suggest that it's rather an incorrect translation _(I think "policies" is meant instead of "political")_ rather than actual censorship circumvention. Not many webhosters would allow outside connections to/from a database server, until you rent a wholly self-managed server.

Comment: @DaleK No Mr, the problem is on my Mysql solution, sql server with Microsoft for example work fine but it's very expansive and tooo slow, now my code is working fine without any changes, the problem was just in my domain subscription package which simply does not allow these operations on professional packages.
the result was very satisfying: vb6 desktop application that reads and saves data on my online server 

Comment: @blabla_bingo please read my answer on Dalek, i know what i want and i realize it 

Comment: @HelO'Ween thank you for correcting my bad English language  also thank you for your reactivity, I was able to unblock the situation by updating my hosting to a pro pack that autorize this action.

Comment: @DaleK thank you ! I'm sorry of my bad langage because i'm francophone and in frensh the word "Mr" is to express respect for others ✌

Comment: @DaleK Mr means in our English school "Mister" which is totally respectful, now with these new reflexions we don't know anything anymore ! by the way it's off topic but the meaning is there, my regards

Comment: Mr does mean Mister, but it applies only to a Male person not a Female person, and I haven't told you whether I identify as male or female so you should use gender neutral terms. This [link may help](https://pronouns.org/how). There is something in the terms and conditions for this site, but I couldn't find it. Needless to say, in the age we live in we should never (not just this site) be assuming what pronouns a person goes by. If they don't mention it anywhere then stick to gender neutral.

Comment: Btw, I didn't take it as being disrespectful, I'm just letting you know what is expected on this site and others.

Comment: You might think I'm making a big deal about nothing, but certainly in the English speaking world this is very important social issue right now.

Comment: @DaleK yes I totally agree with you! in the Anglosxone world, words can upset a whole subject on the contrary, on the other hand, with us, it is the idea that counts. thanks for the remark

Answer (score 2):

You can create a simple PHP file on your server that will take the data from your VB6 apps and store it in your database. You can also create a simple PHP file that will query your database and return the results in a format that your app can read. This is the typical way that a VB6 app will interact with a server-side database.

Comment: Mon code vb6 a marché sans problème sur un autre domaine qui autorise "mySql à distant". Donc j'ai pu me communiquer avec ma BD mysql à distant via mon app vb6 c'était juste un problème de mon abonnement qui n'a pas eu les privilèges nécessaires.